# Parallel curve like algorithm for graphs

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Is there a well know algorithm for calculating "parallel graph"? where by parallel graph I mean the same as parallel curve, vaguely called "offset curve", but with a graph instead of a curve. In the best case, it would allow for variable distance for each segment (connection).

Given following picture, where coordinates of nodes connected with red segments are known, as well as desired distance (thickness)

[offset graph http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_MFJaWUFRFCk/TAEFKmfdGyI/AAAAAAAACXA/vTOBQLX4T0s/s320/screenshot2.png](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_MFJaWUFRFCk/TAEFKmfdGyI/AAAAAAAACXA/vTOBQLX4T0s/s320/screenshot2.png)

how can I calculate points of black outlined polygons?

Comment: Where did you get your avatar? That panda is awesome..

Comment: @Xavier: google for "banksy panda"

Comment: I don't get the question. Perhaps you can explain it more clearly?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Straight Seleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_skeleton) strategy. There is an example implementation, [here](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/3.2/doc_html/cgal_manual/Straight_skeleton_2/Chapter_main.html). The algorithm's complexity is documented [here](http://compgeom.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/open/skeleton.html).

In addition, some other methods are documented here, [A Survey of Polygon Offsetting Strategies](http://fcacciola.50webs.com/Offseting%20Methods.htm).

There is a [topic at GameDev](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=564443) as well.

Edit: The [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/) also has an implementation on this since v3.3, [see the API](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/packages.html#Pkg:StraightSkeleton2). The author has [nice presented a test file](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Minkowski_sum_2/Chapter_main.html#Subsection_24.3.3). (Not an implementation.) You can check out the source, however.

Comment: As a footnote, the most straight-forward way is to solve the line equation give two distances; you will have to pick one solution out of potentially a set of 4 solutions, by checking the point lies on what side of the lines.